# Using a package function inside a case_when() raising error tidyR

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

I am using tidyR case_when to and I have this snippet of code inside a mutate:

```
column = case_when(
          is.na(iptools::is_valid(!!sym(ip_col_name))) ~ 'EMPTY / INVALID_IP',
         iptools::ip_in_any(!!sym(ip_col_name), unlist(a)) ~ 'SECOND CONDITION APPLIES' # Raises error
        TRUE ~ NA_character_
        )
```

My problem starts when there is an invalid IP --> the condition in the first line in the case_when will apply, but unfortunately, the second line in the case when (ip_in_any) will trigger and raise an error.

**Note:** ***iptools::ip_is_any*** raises an error if it gets invalid IP as a parameter.

```
# Example 1
Error in iptools::ip_in_any("not-ip", c("127.0.0.1/64")) : Invalid argument

# Example 2
Error in iptools::ip_in_any(NA, c("127.0.0.1/64")) : 
  Expecting a string vector: [type=logical; required=STRSXP].

# Example 3
Error in iptools::ip_in_any(NULL, c("127.0.0.1/64")) : 
  Expecting a string vector: [type=NULL; required=STRSXP].
```

**Can I prevent the second line from triggering if the first line (invalid_ip) already satisfied? If not, anyone has an idea how do it with clear and concise code?**

Comment: Hi, please provide minimal subset of your data, perhaps using `dput()`.

Comment: Did you try changing it (that is, the second sentence) to `!is.na(iptools::is_valid(!!sym(ip_col_name))) & iptools::ip_in_any(!!sym(ip_col_name), unlist(a))`? That is my gutfeeling from your description, but it is a bit hard without a minimal reproducible example.